# Can I get an InstanceMirror of a class without using any constructor in Dart?

Tags: dart, instance, mirroring

Can I get an InstanceMirror without using any constructor in Dart?

More precisely: I have a class with or without any special constructor, yet I'd like to get an InstanceMirror without having to provide a constructor or any arguments at all.

For example PHP offers ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor

Cheers

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me. Can you explain what you actually try to accomplish?

Comment: What's the problem you want to solve?

Comment: I'm currently playing around with mirrors, the prototype pattern and possible implementations of clone() methods. If I could get an InstanceMirror without having to worry about the constructor(s) of a class I could just copy the values from one object to another in the first step. Thus giving me a nice tool for shallow copies. The use of Annotations could then provide a handle to show the need for single values to be deep copied by recursion. Thus leading to a wonderful tool for cloning objects (or to recursion hell, that has yet to be determined).

Comment: Just make an interface that provides a `.empty()` contructor. Then you can use that one to create an "empty" class and copy all the values.

Answer (score 1):

**New**
If the class doesn't have a constructor, a default constructor with no arguments is implicitly created for this class and you can use it.

If a class has one or more explicit constructors, you can create a new instance only by using one of them.

**Old**
I'm not sure if I fully understand your questions, but basically - no. If your class doesn't have a constructor an implicit default constructor is used.

An instance of a class is created with `new SomeClass` which creates a new instance and calls the constructor. There are other ways like literals `{'x': 1, 'y': 2}` but I'm pretty sure this way a constructor is called as well.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit too vague. I explained it a bit more :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you need an InstanceMirror and why can't you use a ClassMirror?
2. Just list all the available constructors from the ClassMirror and then use a constructor with 0 arguments to create a new instance.

The PHP Version says: "Creates a new class instance without invoking the constructor.". For me this totally makes no sense. That's why there are constructors: To be called at creation time.

Comment: ^^ "For me this totally makes no sense." Welcome to PHP!